# Set map id using folium?

Tags: leaflet, folium

I'm using folium (Django/Python). I created a map:

```
def create_map():
    m = folium.Map(location=[9.934739, -84.087502], zoom_start=7 )
    .....
```

folium creates the map in JS this way:

```
   var map_e87b2e996ca04be59a5cfedabc0bf1ad = L.map(
        "map_e87b2e996ca04be59a5cfedabc0bf1ad",
        {
            center: [9.934739, -84.087502],
               .....
        }
    );
```

What I need is a way to set up my own id from folium (Django) instead of the on-the-fly id created by default:  map_e87b2e996ca04be59a5cfedabc0bf1ad

I need to do this because I want to create custom event on the map that affect others part of the html file where this map is embedded .

Comment: did you find a solution? Could you please share it? I have the same problem. Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue. Would you please share the solution.? thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The full id is a combination of `map._name` and `map._id` If you want to override it, you can use something like:

```py
map = folium.Map()
map._name = "map_name"
map._id = "1"
```

then if you call it with `map.get_name()` it will be `map_name_1`

Answer (score 0):

You could reverse the problem, and rather managing the name yourself, use the specific one `folium` assigns in your custom HTML/CSS/JS, which you can access via `some_map.get_name()`.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Here's a fully working solution with Python code examples for both a **single map** and a **dualMap** in Folium with **custom id** that can help affect the map/maps with css from within python (e.g: in a Streamlit app or using branca to inject css...etc)

#### Single Map custom id

```py
import folium

def create_custom_map(map_name, map_id):
    m = folium.Map(location=[36.45, 2.85], tiles='OpenStreetMap', zoom_start=9)
    m._name = map_name
    m._id = map_id
    # Add any other map customization or layers here
    return m

# Create the first custom map
map1_name = 'custom_map_name'
map1_id = '69696969'
map1 = create_custom_map(map1_name, map1_id)

# Save the maps to HTML files
map1.save('map.html')
```

##### Single Map custom id preview

[image]

---

### DualMap custom id

```py
import folium
import folium.plugins

def create_custom_dualmap(map_name, map_id):
    m = folium.plugins.DualMap(location=[36.45, 2.85], tiles='OpenStreetMap', zoom_start=9)
    
    # Customize the ID of the left and right maps
    m.m1._name = f"{map_name}_left"
    m.m1._id = f"{map_id}_left"
    
    m.m2._name = f"{map_name}_right"
    m.m2._id = f"{map_id}_right"
    
    # Add any other map customization or layers here
    return m

# Create the custom DualMap
dualmap_name = 'custom_dualmap_name'
dualmap_id = '123'
custom_dualmap = create_custom_dualmap(dualmap_name, dualmap_id)

# Save the DualMap to an HTML file
custom_dualmap.save('map.html')
```

##### dualMap custom id preview

[image]